# How to find the position of sequentially enlarged elements in default and two-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to find sequentially enlarged elements in an array:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "How many elements in array? array = ";

    cin >> n;

    int *arr = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Element arr[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << "\n#### Founded sequentially enlarged elements ####\n" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] + 1 == arr[i + 1])
        {
            cout << "arr[" <<i<< "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Running the code yields the following output:

> ```
> How many elements in array? array = 7
> Element arr[0] = 9
> Element arr[1] = 13
> Element arr[2] = 1
> Element arr[3] = 2
> Element arr[4] = 3
> Element arr[5] = 4
> Element arr[6] = 81
>
> #### Founded sequentially enlarged elements ####
>
> arr[2] = 1
> arr[3] = 2
> arr[4] = 3
> ```

Why does it not output all sequentially enlarged elements in the array? In the example, the last element `arr[5] = 4` is missing.

How do I get this result:

```
arr[2] = 1
arr[3] = 2
arr[4] = 3
arr[5] = 4
```

Example my code in two-dimensional array:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> m;
    int **arr = new int*[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[m];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "arr[" << i << "," << j << "] = ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "\n#### Founded sequentially enlarged elements ####\n" << endl;
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < m; j++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i] + 1;
            arr[j] = arr[j] + 1;
            if (arr[i][j] == arr[i + 1][j + 1])
            {
                cout << "arr[" << i << "," << j << "] = " << arr[i][j] << endl;
                c++;
            }

            else if (c != 0)
            {
                cout << "arr[" << i << ","<<j<<"] = " << arr[i][j] << endl;
                c = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Because your condition doesn't hold: `arr[i] + 1 == arr[i + 1]` is `4 + 1 == 81`, and that's false. Rethink your algorithm.

Comment: Please copy-paste the output into the question, as text. Avoid linking to images where not needed.

Comment: The very last element doesn't have an `arr[i + 1]`.

Comment: Question updated @Algirdas Preidžius. Please suggest your algorithm if available.

Comment: Also provide an example for 2-D case

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick.

> Inside if conditional checking, the OR '||' operator skips the second condition if the first condition is true

```
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
{

    if(i>0 && i < n-1){//avoid UB
        if ((arr[i] + 1 == arr[i + 1]) || (arr[i]-1==arr[i-1]) )// the second condition will always be skipped when the first is true. So the second condition will be checked only for the last sequential element
        {
            cout << "arr[" <<i<< "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
        }
    }else if(i==0){
        if (arr[i] + 1 == arr[i + 1])
            {
                cout << "arr[" <<i<< "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
            }

    }else{
         if (arr[i]-1==arr[i-1] )// when i = n-1
        {
            cout << "arr[" <<i<< "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Example:

> Let the array be: {9,13,1,2,3,4,81}
>
> When the cursor reaches the element 4 i.e. i=5 it will first check for the condition with the element 81. But since it will be false and there is '||' OR in the conditional checking, the second condition i.e. 'arr[i]-1==arr[i-1]' will be checked, i.e. between the element 4 and 3.

The code could be cleaned and optimized to a certain level but the idea is the catch here.

Comment: Thanks! Please, give an example of your algorithm in a two-dimensional array if# possible. The algorithm is actually needed for a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @MaxNet Can you please provide a test example for 2-d array?

Comment: @MaxNet Do you want to check for individual rows in 2-D array? What if there is a sequence at row breaks? The row ends and the next row begins with the previous sequence? Please provide the detailed explanation for 2-D arrays in your question.

Comment: Link not work. The requested URL /0F40QA] was not found on this server. @Vidor Vistorm

Answer (score 0):

Your code has logical error .You are comparing the both arr[i]==a[i+1],if those ar equal you are printing the arr[i] which is present element.you are refused print the second element.thats why whenever arr[5] == arr[4] but not equal to arr[6] so thats why it is not displayed.

Here is the following code which generates the results which you expected.

look at the for loop.add following things to your for loop.

```
int c=0;//checking if sequence is found
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] + 1 == arr[i + 1])
    {
        cout << "arr[" <<i<< "] = " << arr[i] << endl;
        c++;//increasing the counter if sequence is found
    }
    else if(c!=0)
    {
        cout << "arr[" <<i<< "] = " << arr[i] << endl;//printing the seccond element to if further comparison returns false.
        c=0;//reset counter which tells that sequence is over.
    }

}
```

Comment: you cause a nice amount of UB with this. `i <=n` means that i will equal length of the array. eg. if it is `n=9;` then  `arr[i]` will be `arr[9]` you will access the element 9 (UB) and element 10 (`arr[i + 1]`) extra UB!

Comment: yeah ..sorry which i forgot remove that.i just added while i was debugging the code.It doesnt need extra i<=n .i will edit.Thanks

Comment: when `i` would be equal to `n` or `n+1` we would get `arr[n+1]` and `arr[n+2]`..out of bounds!

Comment: Didnt fix it, when `i = n-1` in the last of the loop, you still do `arr[i + 1]` which is UB!

Comment: Still an issue with `i+1` when `i=n-1`

Comment: Does your algorithm work in a two-dimensional array? @SrikanthMargam

Comment: have a look at the edited one guys.basically i started debugging into get the answer for output which is provided by him.S0,i didnt check for other o/ps..It works now.

Comment: please, give an example of your algorithm in a two-dimensional array if possible @Srikanth Margam

Comment: It is very helpful to implement the algorithm if we have the problem.can you provide what actually implement with two dimensional arrays.?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm is actually needed for a two-dimensional array. @Srikanth Margam